# Artificial Intelligence in web application by AI specific languages

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence, swi-prolog

Is there any way to integrate prolog or lisp programming with web based application? Actually I want to give some intelligence in my website.

Comment: have you checked this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167397/lisp-web-frameworks

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790994/prolog-web-programming

Comment: OH! I didn't. Thanks. This is it that all I needed. I googled that earlier but I can't find any result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SWI-Prolog [site](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) is *entirely* run by, well, SWI-Prolog. Then if you can run SWI-Prolog on your host machine, you can reuse the same technology.

Of course this make sense if you have to 'publish' some application that can benefit of some the particular strengths of Prolog.

SWI-Prolog is particularly focused on [Semantic Web](http://www.swi-prolog.org/web/index.html).
But it isn't an easy theme, and you could miss some 'high level' user presentation that we are acquainted on today sites (CMS, WordPress, ...).

Otherwise you could use some conventional front end, and 'call' your logic as a Web service.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do this. Either through embedding c libs or what I recommend is checking out http://clojure.org/ it is a lisp port that will run on the JVM. So it is deployable to your servlet container. There is also http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/ but I haven't tried it before. The GNU java prolog looks to be about the same thing, just with prolog.